# Zend_lucene, indexing text stuffs

Tags: php, zend-framework, lucene

Im using Zend_Lucene to search in text files.

```
$index = Zend_Search_Lucene::create ('cachedir');
$doc = Zend_Search_Lucene_Document_Html::loadHTML (file_get_content('source.html'), false, 'UTF-8');
$index->addDocument($doc);
$hit = $index->find(findmeeeh);
```

this does work, but it doesn't seem to use indexes. What I want: if I search for a word, this shouldbe indexed and find faster. I don't understand what they are writing here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html ...

Comment: how indexed? by what you would indexing html document?

Comment: By an value. By any content. Or maybe thats what I dont understand?

Comment: Don't get what you want maybe read more and update your question: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.html-documents

Comment: what I want is when a word is found, let it be indexed, so that new searches will go on faster. Btw, its hard to explain really, its not a database table with columns which can be indexed

Comment: when you add to `Zend_Search_Lucene` that document gets indexed so I don't get what more you need that's optimized database for searching.. maybe you want cache? after first search store results into cache and on second load from cache? in that case look at `Zend_Cache`